# INSERT INTO SELECT - Change a value

Tags: mysql

How would I change a value of a column when using the [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) which copies data from one table and inserts it into another table. See example (pic below)

I'm trying to copy data from one (main) table to another table but update a value on 2nd table.

[image]

**Code:**

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE volume = 'Story of a Girl
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to `UPDATE` an existing record. No need to insert?

Comment: Hey! No. I'm trying to copy data from one table to another table but update a value of the username column on the 2nd table. I don't want the 2nd copy table to have "admin" under the username.... I want it to say "tim"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (username, volume, name, image, content, cssanimate) 
    SELECT 'tim', volume, name, image, content, cssanimate 
    FROM table1 where volume='Story of a Girl';
```

If you list the columns you want to insert, you can replace columns with custom values.

You can get more complex too:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (username, volume, name, image, content, cssanimate) 
    SELECT 
        CASE username
            WHEN 'admin' THEN 'tim' 
            ELSE username 
        END CASE, 
        volume, name, image, content, cssanimate 
    FROM table1;
```

Comment: That is correct. To copy all values you can omit "`WHERE`". I provided a second example that fine tunes based on column value.

Answer (score 3):

You can also modify columns at insert by using

```
INSERT INTO ...() SELECT ...REPLACE(fieldname, 'somestring','anotherstring') ...
```

Or even use a subquery

```
INSERT INTO ...() SELECT ...(SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE somefield = 'asd')...
```

Comment: Would you mind linking to a documentation where this syntax is explained?

Answer (score 0):

Insert into is not the right option, you'll have to use the UPDATE option.

Try using:

```
UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.username = table_1.username FROM table_1 AS table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 AS table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id WHERE table_1.volume = 'Story of a Girl';
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but thanks for the feedback!