# Want year to be populated into table instead of date in SQL table column

Tags: mysql

What should I add after the PublishYear so that when I insert a date into the table, the year part of the date is automatically populated into the column?

CREATE TABLE BOOK(
BOOKId ....,
Book title....,
Author....,
PublishYear integer,
)

I cannot find the solution though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a trigger to automatically assign a value to specific column on a new insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632006/using-a-trigger-to-automatically-assign-a-value-to-specific-column-on-a-new-inse)

Comment: Why don't you just add a datetime field and set the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: I am asking it is possible to add something instead of integer so that if i insert a date in that column it automatically extracts the year on its own. If it is not possible then i will abandon the question.

Comment: This could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153872/insert-into-select-change-a-value

Comment: There's no way to make it automatically replace the date with the year whenever you assign to that column. But if you're loading the data from a file with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, you can do calculations there to convert the input value to a different value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`year` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html), you can insert full dates *if* strict SQL mode is off.

```
create table book(
  published_in year
);

set sql_mode='';

-- This will be truncated to 1999
insert into book(published_in) values ('1999-03-04');
```

It's not recommend to turn strict mode off in general, but you could do it temporarily.

---

I do not recommend this solution. [When I consider what your situation might be to want this, I can think of better solutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).